# Windows 8/10 doesn't want to connect to my home network

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10, internet-connection

I've been having this problem for a while now, and upgrading to windows 10 didn't help. Basically, my pc is perfectly fine with connecting to literally every other network in the world, but when it comes to my home wifi, it says it can't connect to it. Meanwhile, nobody else who has tried to connect has had this problem. What could this be? I have tried forgetting the network, restarting, resetting the network adapter and TCP/IP, all to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

If other devices can connect to your network and it is just your PC that can not, try changing wireless setting from 4Ghz to 2Ghz.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a simple issue with either:
1. Wireless Encryption
2. Wireless Standards

Try disabling the wireless encryption temporary and see if you are able to connect. If you are, you may need to set the encryption standard to something like WEP which is insecure, however, you will have no choice since your device not be able to support newer standards like WPA2.

It is also possible that your router is using N only mode which could be an issue if your PC does not support this standard. Try checking your network settings.

Answer (score 0):

Go into device manager and update your driver for the mix card or wireless adapter it happend to me too

Comment: OS upgrade should have updated the driver too